# How can values be cached in an Elixir function?

Tags: elixir

First, the counter function:

In C++ I can do the following to cache a value across function calls (shamelessly copied from [TutorialsPoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_quick_guide.htm)):

```
void func( void ) {
   static int i = 5; // local static variable
   i++;
   std::cout << "i is " << i ;
   std::cout << " and count is " << count << std::endl;
}
```

Second, a database cacheing example:

```
defmodule ElixirTesting do

  def test_static_function_variable do
    IO.puts(get_value_from_db_cache("A"))
    IO.puts(get_value_from_db_cache("B"))
    IO.puts(get_value_from_db_cache("A"))
    true
  end

  defp get_value_from_db_cache(key) do

    # We want this to be static.
    data_cache = %{}

    if !Map.has_key?(data_cache, key) do
      # Scope of this assignment is limited to local if block so does not re-bind static variable.
      data_cache = Map.put_new(data_cache, key, get_value_directly_from_db(key))
    end

    data_cache[key]
  end

  @db_data %{ "A" => 3, "B" => 4, "C" => 5, "D" => 6 }
  defp get_value_directly_from_db(key) do
    IO.puts("Inside get_value_directly_from_db for key #{key}")
    @db_data[key]
  end

end
```

Console output:

```
Inside get_value_directly_from_db for key A
Inside get_value_directly_from_db for key B
Inside get_value_directly_from_db for key A
```

For both cases how can I achieve the same in Elixir? Or, how should I go about refactoring to accomplish the result using proper functional design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is - you can't. Functional means you program with pure functions, so they always return the same result for the same inputs, caching something inside a function breaks that

Longer answer is - when you want to manage some state, the default in Elixir is to wrap that state in a process. A simple type of process that just keeps a piece of data is called an [Agent](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/agent.html). For example, you can start a named agent, and reference it in your function like so:

```elixir
defmodule Test do
  def start_link(initial_value) do
    Agent.start_link(fn -> initial_value end, name: MyAgent)
  end

  def put(value), do: Agent.update(MyAgent, fn _ -> value end)

  def get, do: Agent.get(MyAgent, fn value -> value end)
end

Test.start_link(:value1)

Test.get() |> IO.inspect() # => :value1
Test.put(:value2)
Test.get() |> IO.inspect() # => :value2
```

Comment: Consider using [`counters`](https://erlang.org/doc/man/counters.html) and/or [`persistent_term`](https://erlang.org/doc/man/persistent_term.html) for global caching.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. So...my concern is that database caching is a use case in which the benefits of FP are challenged by real-world needs. So it sounds like Agents encapsulate mutable data for this purpose. That makes sense browsing the docs, you're right. And interesting Aleksei about these functions; are they callable from  Elixir, what is the syntax?

Comment: Ahem. As any other [tag:erlang] qualified call: `:module.function(arguments)`, e. g. `:persistent_term.get(:my_term_name)`.